# Weird issue with connection timeouts and Google Volley

Tags: android, timeout, android-volley

I have an Android app that uses Google Volley to make requests to a web server backend (http://www.example.com/request.php). The code that requests the webpage is called when the user moves a map.

The issue is that *sometimes* the request fails. When it fails, I open my Chrome browser (also on the phone), and navigate to that "request.php" backend page. The request fails with a connection timeout error. Then I press refresh in Chrome, and it loads correctly. I reopen my app, and then everything works fine again, ie: the request goes through.

**Steps I did to debug:**

1. I switched from the com.loopj Async library to Google Volley -> still has timeout errors
2. Requested a different page (eg: `stackoverflow.com` instead of `example.com/request.php`) when the map is moved -> no errors
3. Added this line to htaccess on the server: `RewriteRule (.*) - [E=Cache-Control:no-cache]` because I had problems with x-litespeed-cache serving cached pages before -> still has timeout errors
4. Tried on multiple devices and Android emulators -> still has timeout errors randomly
5. Filed a ticket with my web host asking if they noticed any timeout errors from my page -> **they said no**

Here's my code:

```
public void updateMarkers() {
    params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("mykey", "myvalue");
    StringRequest fpsr = new StringRequest(Method.POST, "http://www.example.com/request.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //do stuff with the response
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //do stuff with error
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            return params;
        }
    };
    ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(fpsr, "updateMarkers");
}
```

And the `ApplicationController.java` is the same as provided here: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

I highly doubt the code has problems, since requests to pages other than my own never have problems.

The strange thing is, my web host said they didn't notice any timeout errors. But even visiting the page in Chrome for Android had timeout errors that only went away when I pressed refresh.

Can anyone shed light on this? Thank you very much!

Also, I don't have the HTTP response code from the VolleyError. The reason is that it fails randomly, and I don't always have the phone attached to a computer to see the logcat. Also, I tried logging the `error.networkResponse.statusCode` before; it crashed the app due to a null pointer exception.

Comment: I would try visiting your page from a computer and check if you are having timeouts there too, you may also want to try moving your server to a local server as that would ensure you know what is going on with the web server.

Comment: Your server might be a bit overloaded.  Add a retry! http://stackoverflow.com/a/24733287/794088  (dont forget to upvote if you find it helpful)

Comment: The page isn't having timeouts on a computer when it happens on a mobile device. Also, I don't think having it retry would work. It times out on the Chrome browser too (until I press refresh after the error)

Comment: OK, I have tried implementing the retries. It still gives me timeout errors randomly.